# CORS headers not being refreshed due to OutputCache in MVC 4 using the Thinktecture IdentityModel package

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cors, outputcache, thinktecture-ident-model

Presently I am using Thinktecture package for CORS support with my MVC 4 application. on adding the output cache attribute for a method, the CORS support is lost because the HTTP headers are probably cached and the ORIGIN is not modified w.r.t. the request. I know I could use memory cache but it is more tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using VaryByHeader

[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByHeader = "origin;host")]